# How to generate a presigned URL in a case where I dont know the object key value

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I am facing a scenario where I need to create a Presigned URL to upload an object. But I don't know the object's key name. How am I supposed to do this?

May be am not referring to a Presigned URL. However, is there a way that I could do this using .NET AWS-SDK?

Comment: You have to decide what the name of the file will be before you store it. What is your flow?

Comment: Well, it's a feature where file upload is available from the front-end. From what I found so far, I need to create a signature and policy from backend side and then use them for pulpupload s3 upload

Answer (score 0):

First let the front end communicate the file name with you. You can decide the keyname based on this to create your presigned url and send it back to front end to process. But you will require a key name to create a presigned url.

Your other option would be letting the front end call s3 directly but you'll require some other sort of authentication for this (probably cognito).